# How does one extend the Flogger fluent API for domain-specific attributes?

Tags: java, logging

Suppose in my domain, every log statement occurs in the context of a Web request and every request has the context of a user ID, session ID, and cart ID.

Rather than log something like the following:

```
logger.atInfo().log("User %s (session: %s) added product %s to cart %s.", userId, sessionId, productId, cartId);
```

I would prefer something more structured like the following:

```
logger.atInfo().forUser(userId).withSession(sessionId).withCart(cartId).log("product added to cart: %s", productId);
```

or better yet

```
logger.atInfo().forUser(userId).withSession(sessionId).withCart(cartId).product(productId).action(PRODUCT_ADDED).log();
```

https://google.github.io/flogger/benefits#extensibility seems to imply this is possible, but I don't see where.

My hope is that my logging back-end can send a JSON serialization of this info to my ELK stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ScopedLoggingContexts` to add the metadata to every log statement automatically within a scoped context.

That way you don't need to change any existing log statements and it will even work for Flogger log statements in library code you might be using.

```java
ScopedLoggingContexts.newContext().withMetadata(TASK_KEY, value).run(mySubTask(...));
```

or with the simpler "tags" mechanism:

```java
ScopedLoggingContexts.newContext().withTags(Tags.of("label", "value")).run(mySubTask(...));
```

You can also use contexts to do things like enable extra logging during debugging on a per-request basis.

See my new site dedicated to providing better Flogger documentation:
https://hagbard.github.io/the-flogger-manual/advanced/#metadata-contexts-and-scopes

Update (discussing `MetadataKey` and extending the API):

The other way to get slightly more type safety with the API is to use `MetadataKey` instead of `Tags`. A `MetadataKey` is strongly typed, accepts any value type, and can be customized (by making subclasses of `MetadataKey`) as to what it emits.

```java
logger.atInfo().forUser(userId).withSession(sessionId).withCart(cartId).log("product added to cart: %s", productId);
```

could then be:

```java
logger.atInfo().with(SESSION_ID, session).log("product added to cart: %s", productId);
```

where `SESSION_ID` is a `MetadataKey<SessionInfo>`, which contains the user, session and cart IDs. And if the key is a subclass with the `emit()` method overridden, it can control how the IDs are presented.

But if session information is something you want to add to every log statement, save yourself a lot of hassle and use `ScopedLoggingContents` to add it (automatically) to every log statement in the session.

However, if you really want to, you can also create your own subclass of `AbstractLogger` with an extended API (this is what `GoogleLogger` is). This lets you change things like parsing, formatting, and the available API methods.

If you do this however, you probably still want to avoid using that custom logger in common libraries since it forces a new dependency on users. My philosophy in Google was always that "if you really have a great use case that's helping your project do logging better, we should just roll it into the core library rather than having teams each make their own APIs". Logging is a very cross cutting concern and it's unlikely one project will have a problem nobody else has.

In Google many hundreds of projects use Flogger, and only one or two ever had a sufficiently distinct use case which made it worth extending the core API itself. API extension, while "cool" was considered a "last resort" due to the extra maintenance burden it created.

One *BIG* warning about extending the API however is that it opens you up to a new class of breaking changes (i.e. if Flogger ever also happens to pick a new API method with the same name/signature). So, make sure to name new methods with names that are very unlikely to be useful in the core API.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. This certainly shows me how to populate the context of a log record, but I don't understand if this enables me to make a fluent API for logging. It seems the keys and values are still arbitrary (as they should be in this API). I had hoped to further constrain the API to a specific schema with a fluent interface.

Comment: Originally when I designed Flogger I was also thinking that it would be good to have the ability to constrain the API in interesting ways for different use cases, but over time I've changed my mind somewhat. The cost of seeing distinct logging APIs (in terms of core API methods) is a non-trivial cognitive load on developers. It means you need to migrate log statements as code is refactored between code, and it causes issues when two or more use cases clash in the same code.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new class (e.g. `UserLogger`) that extends the Logger and implements your methods, and instantiate your logger with this class.

```java
public class UserLogger extends FluentLogger {

  public UserLogger forUser(Object userId) {
    return super.log("User %s");
  }
...
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I learned that there's also `with(MetadataKey<T>, T)`, which is slightly different from what I asked, but may do the job. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/flogger-discuss/J1pM68LpVvA/Y3pmcld-BQAJ

Comment: As Flogger's author and designer, I don't ever recommend subclassing loggers (in fact I'd have thought `FluentLogger` would be final, and if it isn't that's a bug).

Comment: Ah yes, `FluentLogger` is (correctly) a final class.